# How to modify the value of a primary key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to modify the primary key `integer` of all rows in a table. My goal is to subtract a specific number from the `pk` and then reset it.

Is that possible? Pseudocode:
`update mytable set id = id-100;`

Comment: Try it and see. Do it in a transaction if you need to rollback.

Comment: no no no. never do this. don't ever mess with a PK value like this. postgres won't stop you, but it is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but it is never a good idea. A primary key is there for one purpose only, to identify a row uniquely; once you try to make it serve other purposes, such as being a user-visible sequence number, then you will have problems. In systems that use composite keys that contain business information then there is always nasty code to change key information when it turns out the business information needs to change, a significant part of the argument for using artificial keys is to eliminate the need for this kind of error-prone data-munging. Use a separate column for user-visible sequence numbers and don't mix this concern with that of identifying the row uniquely.

Answer (score 0):

OK I found my error: the number has to be wrapped in single quotes:

`update mytable set id = id - '100' ;`

Comment: For an integer column that does not make any sense to me (since `'` is used for string quoting). That makes me worry even more than @nathanhughes seems to be.

Comment: No, that's completely wrong. `'100'` is not a number, it's a string constant. Don't mix numbers and strings. If that works but `id - 100` doesn't then there is something seriously wrong. **Edit** your question and add the (complete) `create table` statement of the table in question (including the primary key definition)